# Meteor/Mongo - How to write a query to get data from a separate data context

Tags: html, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I've got two separate collections, `Patients` and `Invoices`:

```
Patients Collection

{
  first_name: ...
  surname: ...
  ...
}


Invoices Collection:

{
  invoice_no: ...
  patient_id: ...
  ...
}
```

I want to display a table that shows all the invoices. Amongst the columns, I'd like to show the patient that the invoice is related to (I've got the `patient_id` as one of the fields in the `Invoices` collection).

So I have this helper:

```
Template.showInvoices.helpers({
  invoices: function () {
    return Invoices.find(); // i know this isn't ideal.
  }
});
```

And this is the template:

```
<template name="showInvoices">
  {{#each invoices}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{invoice_no}}</td>
      <td> [PATIENT NAME] </td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

How can I get the patient name from within the invoices data context? Coming from MySQL and relational databases, I can't help but wonder if this is the right design for my particular case because I'm not entirely sure how to perform this query. Should I just change my design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the optional transformation function **[`transform`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection)** that is available when you are defining a collection. The transform option is a function that takes document as a parameter and can be modified. Documents will be passed through this function before being returned from `fetch` or `findOne`, and before being passed to callbacks of `observe`, `map`, `forEach`, `allow`, and `deny` hence this will allow you to embed data from another collecion synonymous to a join.

For example, if you are to refactor your meteor app, you can redefine your `Invoices` collection as follows:

```
Invoices = new Mongo.Collection('invoices', {
    transform: function(doc) {
        doc.patient = Patients.findOne(doc.patient_id);
        return doc;
    }
});
```

Now when you call `Invoices.find().fetch()` in your helper, you will have access to the `patient` property which is a `Patient` document:

```
Template.showInvoices.helpers({
    invoices: function () {
        return Invoices.find().fetch(); 
    }
});
```

**Template**:

```
<template name="showInvoices">
    {{#each invoices}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{invoice_no}}</td>
            <td>{{patient.first_name}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```